# Apex permission error while installing managed package in professional edition

Tags: apex, managed-package, permissions, package, professional-edition

I have built managed package using developer’s edition.
I am using APEX code, classes and triggers in the package to handle certain things.

I have uploaded package as managed-released. The upload was successful.
I then tried installing the package in my Salesforce Professional edition.
I did get below error while installing:

> Your request to install package “Package name” was unsuccessful. None
> of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization
> was affected.  If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce
> CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the following
> information. Problem:
>
> 1. Apex Classes(classes/PhoneNumberFormatTestClass.cls-meta.xml) Missing feature Installing this package requires the following feature
>    and its associated permissions: Apex Classes
> 2. Apex Triggers(triggers/FormatPhoneNumberForLead.trigger-meta.xml) Missing feature Installing this package requires the following feature
>    and its associated permissions: Apex Triggers

When I contacted Salesforce they said:

> There are no limitations around apex and professional edition.  There
> is no restriction on using apex if you start out with an unmanaged
> package, however the issue is with distribution.  You cannot
> distribute an unmanaged package through the appexchange. There is no
> rev share implications.

From what I see in their answer the package should work in my Professional edition.

Does anyone know or suspect why I cannot install the package?

Comment: Does your user profile on your Professional Edition allow you to modify apex code or classes?

Comment: To install managed package in Professional edition, You must be an eligible partner with salesforce.com and your app has to pass the security review. The appropriate permissions will automatically be enabled after you pass the security review. The considerations for using Apex in GE/PE are given in following link, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm

Comment: @Devendra And that should be an answer.

Comment: @battery.cord how/where can I check that?

Comment: @Davendra I have seen this, but from what Salesforce said to me it should work...

Comment: Setup > Manager Users > Profiles > Your Profile > System Permissions, and then check a few relevant permissions: Author Apex, Customize Application, Download AppExchange Packages, Modify All Data. There might be more, but these are at least worth checking. If your profile is set to System Admin, you shouldn't have to worry about permissions.

Comment: @zachu As per the salesforce documentation, they say that first you should be a eligible Salesforce Partner and second thing is need to pass the security review of application. Is there any change from Salesforce on this?

Comment: @battery.cord thanks,  my user is System Administrator, but in the settings I cannot see an option for Author Apex. All other permissions (Customize Application, Download AppExchange Packages, Modify All Data) are set. I don't know why I would need Author Apex permission anyway, if I don't want to edit the package, all I want it's install it.

Comment: @Devendra I think you are right, the app needs to go through review and I need to become partner in order to run it on pro edition. I am just confused because this is what Salesforce told me, and they didn't mention any review etc: There are no limitations around apex and professional edition. There is no restriction on using apex if you start out with an unmanaged package, however the issue is with distribution. You cannot distribute an unmanaged package through the appexchange. There is no rev share implications.

Comment: @zachu You are right, I am putting this as an answer. so that some one who face the same issue can be benefited.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, I have updated the answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm),

> You must be an eligible partner with salesforce.com and your app has
>   to pass the security review. The appropriate permissions will
>   automatically be enabled after you pass the security review.

Also, here are some important considerations for using Apex in GE/PE.

- GE/PE customers can’t create or modify Apex in your app; they can
  only run the existing Apex.
- Your Apex code should not depend on features and functionality that
  exist only in DE, EE, UE, or PXE, or your app will fail to install.
- Make sure to use REST if you plan to expose an Apex method as a Web
  service. Apex classes that have been exposed as a SOAP Web service
  can’t be invoked from an external web app in GE/PE.
- Using Apex to make Web service callouts is allowed in GE/PE. For
  instance, if you’re planning to make a Web service callout to an
  external Web service, as long as the managed package is authorized,
  these classes will function in GE/PE.